# Unable to write avro data to kafka using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using kafka kafka_2.11-0.11.0.2 and confluent version 3.3.0 for schema registry.

I have defined an avro schema as follows:

```
{
"namespace": "com.myntra.search",
"type": "record",
"name": "SearchDataIngestionObject",
"fields": [
  {"name": "timestamp","type":"long"},
  {"name": "brandList", "type":{ "type" : "array", "items" : "string" }},
  {"name": "articleTypeList", "type":{ "type" : "array", "items" : "string" }},
  {"name": "gender", "type":{ "type" : "array", "items" : "string" }},
  {"name": "masterCategoryList", "type":{ "type" : "array", "items" : "string" }},
  {"name": "subCategoryList", "type":{ "type" : "array", "items" : "string" }},
  {"name": "quAlgo","type":{ "type" : "array", "items" : "string" }},
  {"name": "colours", "type":{ "type" : "array", "items" : "string" }},
  {"name": "isLandingPage", "type": "boolean"},
  {"name": "isUserQuery", "type": "boolean"},
  {"name": "isAutoSuggest", "type": "boolean"},
  {"name": "userQuery", "type": "string"},
  {"name": "correctedQuery", "type": "string"},
  {"name": "completeSolrQuery", "type": "string"},
  {"name": "atsaList", "type":{"type": "map", "values":{ "type" : "array", "items" : "string" }}},
  {"name": "quMeta", "type": {"type": "map", "values": "string"}},
  {"name": "requestId", "type": "string"}
]
```

}

And I'm trying to write some data to kafka as follows:

```
value = {
    "timestamp": 1597399323000,
    "brandList": ["brand_value"],
    "articleTypeList": ["articleType_value"],
    "gender": ["gender_value"],
    "masterCategoryList": ["masterCategory_value"],
    "subCategoryList": ["subCategory_value"],
    "quAlgo": ["quAlgo_value"],
    "colours": ["colours_value"],
    "isLandingPage": False,
    "isUserQuery": False,
    "isAutoSuggest": False,
    "userQuery": "userQuery_value",
    "correctedQuery": "correctedQuery_value",
    "completeSolrQuery": "completeSolrQuery_value",
    "atsaList": {
        "atsa_key1": ["atsa_value1"],
        "atsa_key2": ["atsa_value2"],
        "atsa_key3": ["atsa_value3"]
    },
    "quMeta": {
        "quMeta_key1": "quMeta_value1",
        "quMeta_key2": "quMeta_value2",
        "quMeta_key3": "quMeta_value3"
    },
    "requestId": "requestId_value"
}

topic = "search"
key = str(uuid.uuid4())

producer.produce(topic=topic, key=key, value=value)
producer.flush()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "producer.py", line 61, in <module>
  producer.produce(topic=topic, key=key, value=value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/__init__.py", line 99, in produce
  value = self._serializer.encode_record_with_schema(topic, value_schema, value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/serializer/message_serializer.py", line 118, in encode_record_with_schema
  return self.encode_record_with_schema_id(schema_id, record, is_key=is_key)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/serializer/message_serializer.py", line 152, in encode_record_with_schema_id
  writer(record, outf)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/serializer/message_serializer.py", line 86, in <lambda>
  return lambda record, fp: writer.write(record, avro.io.BinaryEncoder(fp))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 979, in write
  raise AvroTypeException(self.writers_schema, datum)
avro.io.AvroTypeException: The datum {'quAlgo': ['quAlgo_value'], 'userQuery': 'userQuery_value', 'isAutoSuggest': False, 'isLandingPage': False, 'timestamp': 1597399323000, 'articleTypeList': ['articleType_value'], 'colours': ['colours_value'], 'correctedQuery': 'correctedQuery_value', 'quMeta': {'quMeta_key1': 'quMeta_value1', 'quMeta_key2': 'quMeta_value2', 'quMeta_key3': 'quMeta_value3'}, 'requestId': 'requestId_value', 'gender': ['gender_value'], 'isUserQuery': False, 'brandList': ['brand_value'], 'masterCategoryList': ['masterCategory_value'], 'subCategoryList': ['subCategory_value'], 'completeSolrQuery': 'completeSolrQuery_value', 'atsaList': {'atsa_key1': ['atsa_value1'], 'atsa_key2': ['atsa_value2'], 'atsa_key3': ['atsa_value3']}} is not an example of the schema {
"namespace": "com.myntra.search", 
"type": "record", 
"name": "SearchDataIngestionObject", 
"fields": [
  {
    "type": "long", 
    "name": "timestamp"
  }, 
  {
    "type": {
      "items": "string", 
      "type": "array"
    }, 
    "name": "brandList"
  }, 
  {
    "type": {
      "items": "string", 
      "type": "array"
    }, 
    "name": "articleTypeList"
  }, 
  {
    "type": {
      "items": "string", 
      "type": "array"
    }, 
    "name": "gender"
  }, 
  {
    "type": {
      "items": "string", 
      "type": "array"
    }, 
    "name": "masterCategoryList"
  }, 
  {
    "type": {
      "items": "string", 
      "type": "array"
    }, 
    "name": "subCategoryList"
  }, 
  {
    "type": {
      "items": "string", 
      "type": "array"
    }, 
    "name": "quAlgo"
  }, 
  {
    "type": {
      "items": "string", 
      "type": "array"
    }, 
    "name": "colours"
  }, 
  {
    "type": "boolean", 
    "name": "isLandingPage"
  }, 
  {
    "type": "boolean", 
    "name": "isUserQuery"
  }, 
  {
    "type": "boolean", 
    "name": "isAutoSuggest"
  }, 
  {
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "userQuery"
  }, 
  {
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "correctedQuery"
  }, 
  {
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "completeSolrQuery"
  }, 
  {
    "type": {
      "values": {
        "items": "string", 
        "type": "array"
      }, 
      "type": "map"
    }, 
    "name": "atsaList"
  }, 
  {
    "type": {
      "values": "string", 
      "type": "map"
    }, 
    "name": "quMeta"
  }, 
  {
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "requestId"
  }
]
}
```

I even trying the same example as given [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) but it doesn't work and throws the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In your exception, there error is saying that the data you are providing it is the following:

```
{'userQuery': 'userQuery_value',
 'isAutoSuggest': False,
 'isLandingPage': False,
 'correctedQuery': 'correctedQuery_value',
 'isUserQuery': False,
 'timestamp': 1597399323000,
 'completeSolrQuery': 'completeSolrQuery_value',
 'requestId': 'requestId_value'}
```

This is much less than what you claim you are providing it in your example.

Can you go back to your original code and on line 60 before you do `producer.produce(topic=topic, key=key, value=value)` just do a simple `print(value)` to make sure you are sending it the right value and that the `value` hasn't gotten overwritten by some other line of code.

Comment: I posted the wrong stacktrace. Thanks for pointing out. But it's actually not getting overwritten. Have edited

Comment: If you do a `pip list`, what version of `avro` do you have installed?

Comment: avro 1.10.0. But I'm using avro from confluent_kafka. `from confluent_kafka import avro`

Comment: Interesting. I tried just using the avro library (not going through kafka) using the data and schema you provided and it didn't have a problem. One thing you might try is to install `fastavro` which confluent_kafka uses by default if it exists. It'd be interesting to know if that works or if it causes a similar error.